# Can a .apk be used to deliver data to a ContentProvider?

Tags: android, add-on

I want to be able to package data in a apk, which is read by my main app.

Is there a way that I can put the data in apk, and then upon install automatically hook that data into the ContentProvider in my main app?

The other possibility is to have each add-on be a content-provider, and have the app look for it, but then I fragment the authorities and I don't have a pre-built list, although I suppose I could "reserve" authorities for expansions if this is the best option.

The other option I understand I might be able to use for data sharing is to run the separate apk's with the same user_id? Any thoughts how I could get this to work would be great too, I tried this but reflection didn't show my addons classes, and it brings up all kinds of dynamic loading questions.

Edit: If it helps, I already have it working using zip files in a folder in the SD, but I want to be able to put that zip into a apk, and write a simple wrapper so that it can be read by my other app.

Answer (score 1):

I plan to do something similar with each add-on being a content provider.  My plan is to have each add-on/content-provider have a common meta-data tag that the main app can look for when iterating through the list of all content providers.

Comment: I actually have done this. I put each content provider on a authority I designated, and then search all available content providers, querying the ones that match my authority for their data.

Answer (score 1):

I actually achieved this, by using a set authority and then iterating over all the content providers.

So every addon is in addons.myapp.blah1... and then if it matches the beginning addons.myapp I do the load.